# HttpSession invalidate is redirecting to login page

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters, session-fixation

Hi I'm using servlet filter to change session ID on every request in order to avoid session fixation. My problem is when the method doFilter ends the application is redirected to login page. I just want to invalidate and create new session, without redirect. I don't have any other filter.

There is my doFilter code:

```
HttpSession session= httpServletReq.getSession();
    
if(session!=null){
  User u = session.getAttribute("user");
  session.invalidate();

  HttpSession newSession = httpServletReq.getSession(true);
  newSession.setAttribute("user", u);
}

chain.doFilter(req, resp);
```

The pattern on filter is `***.xhtml**`

Why am I getting redirect to login?

Is it ok to change session ID on a filter?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *change session ID on every request in order to avoid session fixation*

You should do exactly that instead of invalidating the session. You can use [`HttpServletRequest#changeSessionId()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/servlet/http/httpservletrequest#changeSessionId--) for this.

```
HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession(false);
    
if (session != null) {
    httpRequest.changeSessionId();
}

chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

Do note that [`HttpServletRequest#getSession()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/servlet/http/httpservletrequest#getSession--) defaults to auto-creating the session, so it actually never returns `null`. You need to explicitly pass `false` to [`HttpServletRequest#getSession(boolean)`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/servlet/http/httpservletrequest#getSession-boolean-).

That said, you don't necessarily need to perform this on every request, it's sufficient to perform that only at the moment when you login the user.

Answer (score 0):

You only need method `session.invalidate()`.

When you call 'session.invalidate()`, the existing session will be invalidated.

so the servlet request will create new session to network.

Comment: Thanks for answering, if i remove getSession code after invalidate the old session, how can I set my user object into created from request new session?

Comment: In this case, you'd better use request scope parameter than session. because you want to invalidate existing session so it means you will not use the session. however you also want to maintain the User data. it's not common situation. so, I recommend if you want to keep and use User data then you'd better save the User data in HttpServletRequest(in your case, httpServletReq)